# How to shorten the list of enough conditions of a simple theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be a symmetric binary relation.

Let it's known that $f \subseteq \nu$ for a binary relation $\nu$.

We need to prove $f \circ f \subseteq \nu$.

For this it is obviously enough any one of the following inequations:

1. $\nu \circ \nu \subseteq \nu$;

   $\nu \circ \nu^{- 1} \subseteq \nu$;

   $\nu^{- 1} \circ \nu \subseteq \nu$;

   $\ldots \subseteq \nu^{- 1}$;

   $\ldots$

The question is: Can we shorten the theorem conditions, not to enumerate more
than three different enough conditions?

Comment: Yes, you can.  You will get a shorter theorem :).  I am not sure though what is the current statement of your theorem.

Comment: It looks to me that all of your listed sufficient conditions may fail, and still you may have $f\circ f\subseteq \nu$.